# Do I need to manually preserve state with Azure Durable Functions' CreateTimer method?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm using timers for the first time in my durable orchestration. I found CreateTimer has an [overload that acceptes an object of type `T`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.durableorchestrationcontext.createtimer?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#:%7E:text=Any%20state%20to%20be%20preserved%20by%20the%20timer.) which is returned after firing, and which is meant to represent the state I want to preserve.

I wonder what type of state is meant by this? It is my understanding that the state is preserved in any case by the orchestrator function. Thus, since the orchestrator is re-executed before resuming the code `after` the `CreateTimer<T>` line, state should not be needed to manually preserved.

Am I wrong here? Can somebody please shed some more light on this?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that everything will be replayed and there should not really be a need to pass any type of state for anyone using the durable functions extension. The main reason I think the overload exists is because of the durabletask library where the OrchestratorContext class has such a method which is used internally by DurableOrchestrationContext. This library is not meant to only be usable with azure durable functions but can be used for any longrunning orchestraton work. From readme github.

> The Durable Task Framework (DTFx) is a library that allows users to write long running persistent workflows (referred to as orchestrations) in C# using simple async/await coding constructs. It is used heavily within various teams at Microsoft to reliably orchestrate long running provisioning, monitoring, and management operations. The orchestrations scale out linearly by simply adding more worker machines. This framework is also used to power the serverless Durable Functions extension of Azure Functions.

From the samples from their github it seems to mainly be used for debugging and testing purposes to keep some state of e.g. number of retries.